# Can't print to parallel port LPT1 on docking station in Win7

Tags: windows-7, printing, docking-station, parallel-port

I have a POS printer MicroPOS ADP400. On a desktop PC I connect it to parallel port on MBO and print like this `copy file.txt LPT1:`and it works.

On my HP Probook laptop with LPT port on a docking station it won't print. I get `1 file(s) copied` message from command prompt but it doesn't print. Where to look for logs? How to print from command prompt in Win7-64 to parallel port on a docking station? I thought it is the same thing like on desktop PC but it seems that is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Windows device manager, section Ports to see if you see the parallel port there.

That should tell you which LPT port it is using. It shows as the last part of the line as "(LPTx)". Most likely it isn't LPT1.

If you don't see the port at all, it also requires drivers before it is recognized by Windows.  These drivers should be obtainable from the manufacturer of the docking station.

**EDIT**
Based upon some extra information in the comment it seems Windows, in this case, sees the port, but doesn't automatically generate the DOS style LPTx device in the CommandPrompt environment.

The trick is here to install a dummy Windows printer on this port (Use the "Generic Text-only" printer-driver.)
Then share this printer.
In the command prompt issue the command "net use LPT1 \XXXXX\printer /persistent:yes"
Replace "XXXXX" with the name of your computer and use for "printer" the share-name given to the printer in the previous step.

This maps the LPT1 port on the printer-share. (You could use LPT2, LPT3 etc. if LPT1 would conflict with an already existing printer-port.)
After this is done commands like "copy file.txt LPT1:" will work as normal. The fact that the printer has a Windows printer-driver installed on top of it won't interfere with the operation when accessing it from the Command Prompt.

Comment: I can see it in `Device Manager` as `ECP Printer Port (LPT1)`. It is the only LPT port I have and the only LPT port listed there. I think it is installed ok. Here is the pic https://s29.postimg.org/5af0m8wkn/lpt1_1.png I don't need it in Windows installed, my 'DOS' program works directly with LPT port.

Comment: @HrvojeT The DOS LPT port is completely different hardware from the far more modern chips used in an external dock (usually the dock has a USB->parallel chip and the port is connected by USB). Windows emulates the DOS style LPT port for use by the command prompt, but in some cases this doesn't happen automatically. I will update the answer with additional instructions..